# Invoke Powershell with Multiple Commands AND show the Powershell window

Tags: c#, wpf, powershell

In the program I'm currently working on, I have 3 Powershell commands I want to run and have the Powershell window open so you can see the progress. The first one is an existing ps1 file which I am running as follows:

```
ProcessStartInfo runner = new ProcessStartInfo("powershell")
{
    Arguments = $@"-ExecutionPolicy Bypass -NoProfile -File ""{scriptPath}"""
};
Process cmd = Process.Start(runner);
```

The code block I had for the next section is not showing a window when it executes:

```
var ps = PowerShell.Create();

string[] msuFiles = Directory.GetFiles(path, "*.msu");
foreach (var item in msuFiles)
{
    ps.AddScript($@"DISM.exe /Online /Add-Package /PackagePath:""{item}"" /NoRestart");
}

string[] cabFiles = Directory.GetFiles(path, "*.cab");
foreach (var item in cabFiles)
{
    ps.AddScript($@"DISM.exe /Online /Add-Package /PackagePath:""{item}"" /NoRestart");
}

ps.Invoke();
```

Short of rewriting the second section to execute like the first, is there a way to run all 3 commands in a single Powershell instance and have the window open so progress is visible? Thanks!

Comment: Why do you need PowerShell? Why not just start the executables directly?

Answer (score 0):

My recommendation is similar to Bill's comment.  I think that calling PowerShell to run executables adds unnecessary overhead to your application.

You could run your commands using a `System.Diagnostics.Process` object.

If you would like to create an output window, you can create a window with a multi-line text box control in it and redirect any output from the commands to that window.

The process output can be accessed by handling the "[Process.OutputDataReceived Event](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.process.outputdatareceived(v=vs.110).aspx)"

Comment: Basically I'm taking existing scripts my organization uses and attempting to integrate their functions into a GUI Launcher. The script in question uses Powershell to run DISM with the given parameters and displays the progress in the Powershell window. Also, if I call them all separately, that's still 3 windows that will open and I want them to go one after another in a single window.

Comment: "I want them to go one after another in a single window" - why does that matter?